# Jquery - How to grab specific data-type of option after that option is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'll jump straight with the markup, then explain what I'm trying to do.

Html select options

```
    <select id="1d" name="camp">
    <option data-url="week_1" value="Week 1">30th July</option>
    <option data-url="week_2" value="Week 2">6th August</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="camp_url" id="1e">
```

Jquery script I'm struggling with. The script below shows the value of the selected option, of course, but I can't find a way to grab to the `data-url` info.

```
    $('#1d').change(function () {
        $('#1e').val($(this).val());
    });
```

Bottom line, I'm needing the `value` of `input#1e` to be the `data-url` of `#1d` upon selection.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about that?

```
$("#1d").on("change", function () {
    var url = $(this).children(":selected").data("url");
    $("#1e").val(url);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/aRzNn/

---

Also personally I enjoy this solution:

```
$("#1d").on("change", function () {
    $("#1e").val(function() {
        return $("#1d > :selected").data("url");
    });
});​
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I kept trying it without `:selected`. No wonder.

Comment: An alternative to getting the selected element: `$('#1e').val($(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).data('url'));`

Comment: @Mathachew It could be used but if you wish absolutely mix jQuery with vanilla use `this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-url")` to get data attribute value.

Comment: cool, never seen a function as the parameter for val(), but is it necessary?  wouldn't `$("#1e").val($("#1d > :selected").data("url"))` work?

Comment: @VisioN Thank you, that's a feature I have barely used, but I was certain there was a way.

Comment: @Rodolfo Yup, it will work fine. Using function as parameter of `val` isn't necessary. I just used it to show the features of jQuery :)

Comment: @VisioN - Don't know if I should start a new question. I'm expanding from this one. I'm using multiple selections, but only one is showing as `:selected` in the DOM. So, once I highlight the second option, the first one's info is removed as it is no longer marked selected though it is still highlighted.