# Jquery - Grab multiple selections' data in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This originates from [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904829/jquery-how-to-grab-specific-data-type-of-option-after-that-option-is-selected). I'm expanding on it.

Html select options

```
    <select id="1d" name="camp" multiple="multiple">
    <option data-url0="week_1" value="Week 1">30th July</option>
    <option data-url1="week_2" value="Week 2">6th August</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="camp_url0" id="1e">
    <input type="hidden" name="camp_url1" id="1f">
```

Jquery script I'm struggling with.

```
    $("#1d").on("change", function () {
    var url1 = $(this).children(":selected").data("url0");
    var url2 = $(this).children(":selected").data("url1");
    $("#1e").val(url0);
    $("#1f").val(url1);
});
```

This code works beautifully (maybe not the cleanest?), except for one important issue. Even though it is a multiple selector, whenever both options are selected, only one `option` is marked as `:selected` in DOM, meaning only one `data-url{row_id}` is being inputted. I need both, if both are selected.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have posted my solution regarding your comment in the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904829/jquery-how-to-grab-specific-data-type-of-option-after-that-option-is-selected/10904860#comment14219762_10904860): http://jsfiddle.net/aRzNn/2/.

Comment: @VisioN Almost, Neal below has it almost. Your version doesn't separate the data per unique id. I really appreciate your help in this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD**:

Add some additional “routing” data to the html

```
<select id="1d" name="camp" size="5" multiple>
    <option data-url="week_1" data-id="1e" value="Week 1">30th July</option>
    <option data-url="week_2" data-id="1f" value="Week 2">6th August</option>
</select>
```

and use it

```
$("#1d").on("change", function () {
    $('input[type=hidden]').val('');

    $('option:selected', this).each(function() {
        $('#' + $(this).data('id')).val($(this).data('url'))
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ctDC/1/

**OLD**:

Just [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) it and you will get an array with the data.

```
$('option:selected', this).map(function() {
    return $(this).data('url')
})
```

`["week_1", "week_2"]`

http://jsfiddle.net/5ctDC/

Comment: Thanks @o_nix. However, this doesn't separate them out for my different input fields (data_url0, data_url1, etc...). It simply lists them for one input field. Neal's option is perfect minus the added "undefined" for unselected options.

Comment: I don't know. Just thought that was the best way to grab them. Aren't they needed to input the selected options one at a time in fields? I'm amateur on Jquery.

Comment: Yes! Except with that, once unselected, it doesn't clear out.

Answer (score 0):

Go through **ALL** of the selected elements:

```
$("#1d").on("change", function () {
    var allurl1 = '', allurl2 = '';
    $(this).children(":selected").each(function(){
        allurl1 += $(this).data("url0");
        allurl2 += $(this).data("url1");
    });
    $("#1e").val(allurl1);
    $("#1f").val(allurl2);
});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/mtAgS/ (I made the inputs shown so you can visually see what happens)

Comment: The only problem with this is that it adds "undefined" to unselected option.

Answer (score 0):

In an unrelated note, you should'nt be using id that don't start with a letter.

Comment: Why not? `$('#1d')` works perfect. Shouldn't I use `id="some-element"` for example? :)